# How to shift object in Immutable Js Ordered map.?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, immutable.js, shift

I am working with **redux**, configured state as [Immutable Js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) **Ordered Map**.

#### Below is the state:

```
{
  "layers": {
    "items": {
      "yrgroih9": {
         "width": '300px',
         "x": '700px',
         "y": '700px'
       },
       "qhy0dukj": {
         "width": '160px',
         "x": '500px',
         "y": '500px'
       },
       "7lw2nvma": {           //Target object
         "width": '250px',
         "x": '300px',
         "y": '300px'
       },
       "jdkhsd9d": {
         "width": '280px',
         "x": '100px',
         "y": '100px'
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to shift the key `7lw2nvma` one step up, & below is i want:

```
{
  "layers": {
    "items": {
      "yrgroih9": {
         "width": '300px',
         "x": '700px',
         "y": '700px'
       },
       "7lw2nvma": {           //Shifted object
          "width": '250px',
          "x": '300px',
          "y": '300px'
        },
       "qhy0dukj": {
         "width": '160px',
         "x": '500px',
         "y": '500px'
       },
       "jdkhsd9d": {
         "width": '280px',
         "x": '100px',
         "y": '100px'
       }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reducer code:

```
import { OrderedMap, fromJS } from 'immutable';

export default function myApp(state = new OrderedMap, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHIFT_OBJECT':
      var shiftObj = "7lw2nvma";   //Known value
      //return state.getIn(["layers","items"]).shift(shiftObj); // Something like this to shift object.
  }
}
```

Help me to get the desired output.

**Note:** If it is not possible in OrderedMap, then say with List.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer based on `sortBy` function in **Immutable Js OrderedMap.**

Now i added `index` values in that object as shown below:

```
{
  "layers": {
    "items": {
      "yrgroih9": {
         "index":0,
         "width": '300px',
         "x": '700px',
         "y": '700px'
       },
       "qhy0dukj": {          //Another known value
         "index":1,
         "width": '160px',
         "x": '500px',
         "y": '500px'
       },
       "7lw2nvma": {           //Target object (shift up)
         "index":2,
         "width": '250px',
         "x": '300px',
         "y": '300px'
       },
       "jdkhsd9d": {
         "index":3,
         "width": '280px',
         "x": '100px',
         "y": '100px'
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I have two known values `7lw2nvma` & `qhy0dukj`.

Using `setIn` changed `7lw2nvma` index as 1 & `qhy0dukj` index as 2.

Using `sortBy` function i can sort object based on modified index values.

```
var getSorted = state.getIn(["layers","items"]).sortBy(function(value, key) {
  return value.get("index");
});
```

And now the state items sorted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify directly your state. That is forbidden for an immutable.
You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign) to create a new one.

```
return Object.assign({}, state.getIn(["layers","items"]).shift(shiftObj))
```

EDIT: You can use an array of your keys, sort it as you like and construct a new object for your state.
Something like:

```
let tab = Object.keys(state.getIn(["layers","items"]))
tab.sort() // sort keys by name

const obj = tab.reduce((o, key) => Object.assign(o, {[key]: state.getIn(["layers","items"])[key]}), {}) //contruct a new object from your ordered array and current state, you can also create another const on state.getIn(["layers","items"]) to increase perfs
console.log(obj)
return obj
```

Comment: There is no 'shift' function in Immutable js. Just to do something like functionality, i have used the name 'shift'. Is there anything other options to achieve the result..?

Comment: I think you have edited code based on array with indexing like: 0,1,2,ect.. But i need to do that without array indexing, only using object type how to achieve that..?

Comment: Objects are not ordered, they are key-value typed. And there is no object methods to move, order or insert element at a specific position. Using a temporary array is probably the easiest way to do that.

Comment: So your answer will not fit for my key-value typed objects.. Thanks for your effort.  I found an answer and it is explained below..

Comment: It will, my code returns a key-value object. Did you tried it ?
https://jsfiddle.net/swko5oz6/

Comment: Yes i checked your answer. Its ordered in this way 7lw2nvma,jdkhsd9d,qhy0dukj,yrgroih9  but i need to order
in this way yrgroih9,7lw2nvma,qhy0dukj,jdkhsd9d. Can you modify this?

Comment: So I suppose you want to sort your objects by key name ? If it's what you expect, just use `tab.sort()` instead of both `tab.splice`. And you won't need `shiftObj` and `index` anymore.

Comment: Please use that sort method and post your answer. I will accept your answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Your answer updated, but the keys are not sorted as i expected.. I added  your updated code in your [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/swko5oz6/2/).. Check that keys arrangement in console.

Comment: I don't know  how you want to sort your object (visibly in a random order) or if it's always the same just harcode your fu***ng tab and start to think by yourself

Comment: Cool.. Have you read and understand my question clearly..? Have your code output(sorted object) seems same as i showed in my question(second code with shifted output)..?